# Magento 1.7.2 Adwords remarketing tag crashes product view page

Tags: php, magento, dynamic, google-ads-api

I would like to add a dynamic remarketing tag to the View.phtml file. I'm using this code:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');?>
<?php if ($_product && $_product->getId()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: '<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>',
ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
ecomm_totalvalue: '<?php echo $_product->getfinalprice(); ?>',
}
</script>
```

This code occupies lines `182` to `190` of my `View.phtml` file.

When I insert the code into the file, I get the following error message

```
"Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected $end in (pathfile for view.phtml file) on line 190"
```

But line `190` is only occupied by the `</script>` tag

I cannot see any bracket or parenthesis missing or showing up where it shouldn't.

Can somebody please point out to me where the error could be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last ',' is involved.

Try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: '<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>',
ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
ecomm_totalvalue: '<?php echo $_product->getfinalprice(); ?>'
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 Makinovic

and a semi-colon after a variable affectation ?

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');?>
<?php if ($_product && $_product->getId()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var google_tag_params = {
  ecomm_prodid: '<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>',
  ecomm_pagetype: 'product',
  ecomm_totalvalue: '<?php echo $_product->getfinalprice(); ?>'
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the colon syntax with an if statement such as

```
if ($_product && $_product->getId()):
```

you need to close with an `endif;` statement.

Add the following below your `</script>` tag:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```